# Passing more than just the resultant page out of a Flask POST

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, werkzeug

(Flask novice alert)

Given the following to upload and save a file in Flask:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return render_template_string('''
                {% extends "base.html" %}
                {% block content %}
                <h4>File uploaded</h4>
                <p><a href={{ url_for('members_page') }}>Back</a></p>
                {% endblock %}
                ''')
        elif not allowed_file(file.filename):
            return render_template_string('''
            {% extends "base.html" %}
            {% block content %}
            <h3>Please try again</h3>
            <h4>File must be a .csv</h4>
            <p><a href={{ url_for('upload_file') }}>Back</a></p>
            {% endblock %}
            ''')
    return render_template_string('''
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block content %}
    <h4>Upload CSV of Company/URL data</h2>
                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="file" />
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
    {% endblock %}
    ''')
```

I wish to make `filename` available within another function:

```
@app.route('/scrape', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required                                 # Use of @login_required decorator
def scrape():
    parser = ConfigParser()
    parser.read('config.ini')
    keywords = parser.get('scrape', 'keywords').replace(' ', '').split(',')
    jobs = scraper.scrape(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename), keywords)
```

The above is the **desired** intent, where `filename` is known by the scrape fucnction. Obviously that is not yet the case. With `upload_file()` already having a return value in the positive case (a confirmation page), how can I make `filename` available? `UPLOAD_FOLDER` will contain more than just the uploaded file, so I can't just join this path with whatever is in there.

Where this a non-Flask program, I would probably return `locals()` and then access the appropriate key, but I imagine that's not possible here if I want to maintain the serving up of the confirmation page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to somehow connect two requests. If many users request the first one, a then someone requests a `/scrape`, how do you know which one is requesting, and which filename does he belong to?

1. You can use a session (a cookie session for example, see http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/) to keep track of the uploaded file. Store the filename in the session, and the when the same user (with the same cookie) requests `/scrape`, you can retrieve the filename from the user session.
2. You can include the filename to use in the second request. This way, the user himself has to keep track of the files that he uploaded.

In either case, but especially in the latter, it's important to think about ownership of files: which user has access to which file on your system?

Comment: Thanks; useful suggestions and considerations for me to keep in mind for whenever I nee to attempt something similar for many users and/or files. As it is, a more back-to-basics approach will suffice. See below.

Comment: See my comment there. If you don't care at all which file you are taking, just take the last file you've saved. You can do that for example by naming them after the date, or use the filesystem to find the last file that has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

Pickle the filename in `upload_file()`, unpickle it in `scrape()`.

```
PICKLED_CSV_FILENAME = 'pickled_csv_file_name'

def pickle_filename(filename, pickle_file):
    with open(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, pickle_file),'wb') as p:
        pickle.dump(filename, p)

def load_pickled_filename(pickle_file):
    return pickle.load(open(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, pickle_file), 'rb'))
```

in `upload_file()`:

```
pickle_filename(filename, PICKLED_CSV_FILENAME)
```

then in `scrape()`:

```
jobs = scraper.scrape(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], load_pickled_filename(PICKLED_CSV_FILENAME)), keywords)
```

pickle_filename(filename, PICKLED_CSV_FILENAME)

Obviously not a sustainable solution in the case of many users/files, but it is a single user, single file scenario so it's acceptable.

Comment: I don't think this will help much. Then you have exactly the same problem: which file are you going to unpickle?

Comment: I've pickled the filename, not the file. I then unpickle the filename.

Comment: Yes, but where is the pickled filename?

Comment: If you do this, why don't you just declare the `FILENAME` globally, use that to save the uploaded file, and also to get it back in the `/scrape` endpoint. This is an obfuscated way to do the same. This is really nonsensical, the whole pickling thing is doing nothing.

Comment: Fair point. I thought I was keeping things simple by pickling rather than some other convoluted method. You've made it *even simpler*. Thank you Gijs.